# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/unity/BuildConfig;

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

[image]

I i add any of the aboves shown in the pi aar or jar file for unity ads , then i get this error :

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2017.4.12f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/unity/BuildConfig;
1 error; aborting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

But if i remove them , then the app build properly but then i get these errors in the logcat

```
/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.agasper.unitynotification.UnityNotificationManager
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.agasper.unitynotification.UnityNotificationManager
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:216)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.agasper.unitynotification.UnityNotificationManager" on path: DexPathList[
```

and this too

```
 E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.unity.ads.UnityAdListener
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.unity.ads.UnityAdListener
```

CAnt really understand the issue .. Please help

Comment: There are many issues that might be there As I can see there Facebook, Admob, Unity Ads many plugins are there that might cause an issue so you need to check for each plugin as well as check your java version might need to be downgrade.

Comment: I tried checking by removing and readding  the plugins and i was able to build but still the problem of UnityNotificationManager class not found stays in the app